# How to pass variable from pug template file to a script file?

Tags: node.js, express, pugjs

From express i pass the variable locals to the template engine like this:

res.render("Main.pug",**locals**);

I can use the variable inside the template engine. But i also want to use it inside the included script file

script(src='/file/Index.js')

i have tried following,

```
script(src='/file/Index.js') 
  | var myVar = "Hello";
```

But not working.

Answer (score -1):

Now its working,

Needs to be above any other script files

> script(type="text/javascript").   var myVar ="test" ;

inside Index.js:

```
alert(myVar)
```

And if you want to use variable passed from express to script file use:

```
 script(type="text/javascript").
  var myVar ="#{JSON.stringify(data)}";
```